# issue with "NSManagedObject" in .Xcdatamodeld file and Core Data in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

when i create a new NSManagedObject from Editor at the top, instead of making just a .h and .m file, it makes 4 itme 2 .h and 2 .m with totally different amount of code how which one can i delete? and how can i make them in the old fashion way which had only 1 .h and 1 .m file?

[image]

there's also another question, when i have 2 entity while making this class, at the section it asked me to " select the entities you want to manage" should i check my 2 entities at the same time? or its better to make the different NSManagedObject for each one of them?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your project on Github so we can see what's going on there?

Comment: there's nothing in it, its a new project with core data checkbox checked, i add entity and attributes after that when im in that entity panel i create an NSManagedObject for every Entity after that when i compite i get the error there's nothing in the project

Comment: I just tried with an empty project and it works fine. You should keep all 4 generated files per entity, do not delete any of them. Did you try to delete the Derived Data folder and restart Xcode?

Comment: yes i did, in Xcode 8 there's no empty project for ios the simplest one is Single View Application! and yes i did try deleting Derived Data folder didn't work yet, do you use XCode 8? how i dont have any empty project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Xcode's code generation tool, you **should not** delete any of the 4 files since the one uses the other.

However, **you don't have to use this tool** and you can write your own implementations without any problem. Just remember to mark the properties as `@dynamic` for the compiler to know they will be implemented during runtime.

[This article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/core-data-code-generation/) explains all the above very well.

Comment: by XCode's code generation tool you mean creating 'NSManagedObject' in editor menu in data model? and if i want to make the impelementations on my own i should make them 4 file just like Xcode make it? or 1 .h 1.m is enough? and also what is those new file for? im watching Lynda Core Data course and since its for 2012 its totally different at some parts thats why im confused!

Comment: Exactly, I mean Xcode's option in the "Editor" menu on top

Comment: i hope you can see this, everytime i try to create that object in entity window which make 4 file, i get the error [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259228/how-to-fix-apple-mach-o-linker-error-group-clang-error-linker-command-faile) and this method is for Lynda which is from 2012 and its really old yesterday i watched udemy course which is new and for ios 9 and higher, he wont do such thing and he do all the stuff in ViewControllers class and nothing more i think this way is completely wrong or deprecated.